# Segmentation fault on realloc ANSI C

Tags: c, pointers, realloc, ansi-c

If I run this code is shown to me "segmentation fault", but if in the "for" of the "create" function I set the clause  i <1 (ie one cycle), the program is working, why?

```
void create(char ***a,int *length){
    int i=0;
    *length = 0;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        ++(*length);
        (*a)=realloc(*a,(*length)*sizeof(char *));
        *(a[i])="Hello\0";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    char **a = NULL;
    int *l = malloc(sizeof(int));
    create(&a,l);
    for (i=0; i<(*l); i++) {
        printf("%s",a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

what I would like is that at the end, the program show me 4 times "Hello"

Comment: Why are you allocating memory for `l` dynamically, instead of just declaring it as a normal non-pointer variable and pass it using the address-of operator? There are also a couple of other things that seems odd, or plain wrong: In the "odd" category is your usage of explicit string terminator in the constant string which is not needed, and in the "wrong" part reassigning back to the pointer you're reallocating (think what happens if `realloc` fails).

Comment: Also, try to avoid being a [three-star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer), it's usually not a compliment.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: So how would you then cover this use-case via a function argument, if not via `T***`?

Comment: @alk By *not* using arguments, and return the pointer instead. The only way I could be made to write a function using a "tripple-pointer" would be if my boss *forced* me to do it (and it would have me start looking for a new job quite quickly if that happened).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: This is not an answer to the question! ;-)

Comment: Also, `free` all allocated memory and also, check `malloc`'s and `realloc`'s return value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
*(a[i]) = ...
```

should be

```
(*a)[i] = ...
```

---

A "string" literal like `"Hello"` already *implicitly* adds a terminating `'\0'` character. So there is no need to specify it *explicitly* like in here: `"Hello\0"`.